# Como consultar 2 tabelas dentro de um banco mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Sou novo com sql e php.

é o seguinte, tenho um sistema de afiliado que preciso trazer a lista de afiliados de um usuario.

pra isso uso:

```
<?php
//traz os usuarios
$query = sprintf("SELECT referral_user_id FROM magry_awoaffiliate_referral where affiliate_user_id = '$userid'");
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
$teste = $linha['referral_user_id'];
?>

<?php
    if($total > 0) {
        do {
?>
<ul>
            <li><?=$linha['referral_user_id']?></li>
</ul>
<?php
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    }

mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Essa consulta me traz a lista de IDs desse usuario, mas preciso pegar o nome de cada usuario que está em outra tabela (magry_users).

Como faço para trazer essa informação?

Na tabela afiliado, tenho o referral_user_id que não tem o nome dele e na tabela magry_users tenho o id (que é o mesmo id de referral_user_id) e o nome do usuário.

Quero trazer aqui o nome:

```
<li><?=$linha['referral_user_id']?> - "nome do usuario"</li>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode usar `INNER JOIN`, exemplo: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo da premissa que dentro da tabela `magry_users` os campos utilizem seus nomes como `id e nome`, utilize esta chamada mySQL:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT `magry_awoaffiliate_referral`.`referral_user_id`, `magry_users`.`nome` FROM `magry_awoaffiliate_referral`
  INNER JOIN `magry_users` ON `magry_awoaffiliate_referral`.`referral_user_id` = `magry_users`.`id`
  WHERE `magry_awoaffiliate_referral`.`referral_user_id`='".$userid."' ORDER BY `magry_awoaffiliate_referral`.`referral_user_id` DESC");
```

Depois disso você poderá usar:

```
<li><?=$linha['referral_user_id'] . ' - ' . $linha['nome']?></li>
```